# End all the div inside a div container dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some html data coming from database dynamically. In some of the html the div is properly closed and some records the the div inside is not properly closed with . 
I put these things into a jquery tab but when the unended div comes the tab stop working. I want something in which the the open div's will be ended dynamically.

Comment: Please share the code you are using.

Comment: You need to post some code. Are you using PHP to interact with DB? If so, you could use PHP to close non ended tags

Comment: You will need to write your code for that.

Comment: No i am using Asp.net for it .

Comment: You can't do this in Javascript as the HTML would already have been rendered. You *could* rearrange the divs to the correct order after they've been rendered but each browser handles this differently and you may end up with unexpected results. Use a server-side technique, or fix the HTML!!

Comment: you mean you want to remove the `div` dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the HTML before it's rendered then it's easy: you let jQuery chew it for you. Example:

```
jQuery("<div>Hello <span>Sir</span>")[0].outerHTML;
```

Will give you:

```
<div>Hello <span>Sir</span></div>
```

So if you are able to get the received HTML in a variable "dbStringName" before it's inserted into the tab so just do

```
var myCleanedUpHTML = jQuery(dbStringName)[0].outerHTML;
```

and put that in your tab.

Comment: +1, and he still can get the _wrong_ html and update it with jquery after the html is rendered.

Comment: @Abdullah Battal I'm not sure that would be possible as I think the inserted "open" DIV would have already "matched up" with the tab's closing DIV. That's might be what was breaking the tabs to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into making sure the html that is put into the database is all closed properly to begin with.

Or you could use javascript's `indexof` to check if the div is properly closed, and if not, add a closing div.

Something like:

```
if (!dbStringName.indexOf("</div>") > -1){
  //add div here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this css to table using div

```
    .containerDiv { 
  border: 1px solid #3697f6;
  width: 100%; display:table
}
.rowDivHeader {
  border: 1px solid #668db6;
  background-color: #336799;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold; display:table-row
}
.rowDiv {
  border: 1px solid #668db6;
  background-color: #cee6fe;
  display:table-row
}
.cellDivHeader {
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  display: table-cell;
  width:12%;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center; 
}
.cellDiv {
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  display: table-cell;
  width:10%;
  padding-right: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.lastCell {
  border-right: none;
}
```